# Product demand down calculation in pandas df without loop

Tags: pandas

I'm having trouble with shift and diff and I feel it is simple?
Assume I have customers with different product demands, and they get handled with priority top down. I'd like to have it efficient without looping....

```
df_situation = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "cust": [1, 2, 3, 3,4],
        "prod": [1, 1, 1, 2,2],
        "available": [1000, np.nan, np.nan, 2000, np.nan],
        "needed": [200, 300, 1000, 1000,1000],
    }
)
```

[image]

My objective is to get some additional columns like this, but it looks like difference calculations and shift operation are in a "chicken and egg problem situation".

[image]

Thanks in advance for any hint

Comment: Could you describe your problem and required solution in a bit more detail? What do you want to happen in not-straightforward situations? From what I understand now, working with dataframes is not very intuitive for what you want to achive...

Answer (score 1):

`leftover_prod` is the available [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html#pandas-series-ffill) - the cumulative demand [`groupby cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-cumsum):

```
a = df_situation['available'].ffill()
df_situation['leftover_prod'] = (
        a - df_situation.groupby('prod')['demand'].cumsum()
)
```

```
0     800.0
1     500.0
2    -500.0
3    1000.0
4       0.0
Name: leftover_prod, dtype: float64
```

`fulfilled_cust` is either the `demand` if there is enough `leftover_prod` or the `leftover_prod` [`groupby shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-shift) + [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
s = (df_situation.groupby('prod')['leftover_prod']
     .shift()
     .fillna(df_situation['available']))

df_situation['fulfilled_cust'] = np.where(
    s.ge(df_situation['demand']), df_situation['demand'], s
)
```

```
0     200.0
1     300.0
2     500.0
3    1000.0
4    1000.0
Name: fulfilled_cust, dtype: float64
```

`missing_cust` is the `demand` - the `fulfilled_cust`:

```
df_situation['missing_cust'] = (
        df_situation['demand'] - df_situation['fulfilled_cust']
)
```

```
0      0.0
1      0.0
2    500.0
3      0.0
4      0.0
Name: missing_cust, dtype: float64
```

Together:

```
a = df_situation['available'].ffill()
df_situation['leftover_prod'] = (
        a - df_situation.groupby('prod')['demand'].cumsum()
)
s = (df_situation.groupby('prod')['leftover_prod']
     .shift()
     .fillna(df_situation['available']))

df_situation['fulfilled_cust'] = np.where(
    s.ge(df_situation['demand']), df_situation['demand'], s
)

df_situation['missing_cust'] = (
        df_situation['demand'] - df_situation['fulfilled_cust']
)
```

```
   cust  prod  available  demand  leftover_prod  fulfilled_cust  missing_cust
0     1     1     1000.0     200          800.0           200.0           0.0
1     2     1        NaN     300          500.0           300.0           0.0
2     3     1        NaN    1000         -500.0           500.0         500.0
3     3     2     2000.0    1000         1000.0          1000.0           0.0
4     4     2        NaN    1000            0.0          1000.0           0.0
```

---

imports and DataFrame used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_situation = pd.DataFrame({
    "cust": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
    "prod": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    "available": [1000, np.nan, np.nan, 2000, np.nan],
    "demand": [200, 300, 1000, 1000, 1000],
})
```

(changed "needed" to "demand" as it appears in image.)

Comment: The np.where move is pretty cool , small adjustment  : df_situation["fulfilled_cust"] = np.where(
    s.ge(df_situation["demand"]), df_situation["demand"], np.clip(s, 0, 1000000)
)    Thank you!